# NoneType object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, nonetype

I am working on a seven-segment display project on Learnstreet. One of the required methods takes the input obtained from a text box which is labelled "inputString". Input String is then passed to the given method using `text` which is a string. Further description of the method is as given below -

> In this method we have got the text from that input string, and we need to extract each character from it, and if it is a number, pass it on to our illuminate function to display that number using a 7-segment display.

Here is my code for parsing the string and extracting digits from the number.

```
def get_digits(text):
    num=int(text)
    while num!=0:
        print illuminate(num%10)
        num/=10
```

This code throws an error :

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "", line 1, in File "", line 27, in test File "", line 17, in test_get_digits TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable.

Because I am new to python, I don't understand what is causing this.Please help

Comment: Show the code of `test_get_digits` function.

Comment: @falsetru the website didn't provide the code for `test_get_digits`. I had to code two methods -`illuminate` and `get_digits` , and those were the only two I could view.

Comment: @VineetKaushik How could that possibly be?

Comment: @KDawG The website makes tutorials for python. So they only provide us the part of the code that is a part of our lesson. I don't know what kind of back end work goes into making something like that. You can look it up if you want to-Learnstreet.com

Comment: @VineetKaushik I suggest your coding on some online IDE cause otherwise how can that error message be generated if you don't have a function named `test_get_digits`

Comment: huh..What's the downvote for? @KDawG like I said you are welcome to look it up. I really have no idea what kind of technology they are working on. I am puzzled about it too but really, there's no other function other than the two I've mentioned.

Comment: @VineetKaushik I understand what your trying to say, looks like you got a long road ahead of you... ~Good Luck!~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the other requirements is to return something. Since your function returns nothing, `None` is implicitly returned, and this causes the test scaffolding to fail. Perhaps you should return a list containing the return values of each invocation of `illuminate()`.

Comment: It worked! However, my code is still falling short of what it needs to  do. But that is entirely my problem.Thank you!

Comment: Also, get used to `//` and `//=`.

Comment: What for? What are `//` and `//=` supposed to do/be?

Comment: Integer division. They make sure that your code will work fine even on (and that you will be ready for) Python 3.x.